# Disable eslint in creare-react-app - specific file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, eslint

I'm trying to disable `Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level` in a specific file but nothing I do seems to work.

someScript.js

```
(function() {
  if (window.hasRun) {
    return true;
  }
  window.hasRun = true;

  import {
    someFunction
  } from "./someFile";
});
```

Commenting `eslint-disable-next-line` or `/* eslint-disable */` doesn't do anything and neither does creating an eslint config or ignore files. Using create-react-app to build.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please show us, in code, where this error is occurring and what you've tried to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable it with `/* eslint-disable */` because it is a **parsing** error, that is, the code is not valid Javascript. Just as the error message suggests, import statements must be located at the top level of the program. If you need conditional module loading, you may use `require('./someFile')`, it might or might not work depending on your environment.

Comment: Indeed how I solved it, just switched import to require to avoid importing if not necessary. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { /* eslint-disable */
    someFunction /* eslint-disable */
  } from "./someFile";/* eslint-disable */
});
```